# iOS static library .a file not included

Tags: iphone, ios, static-libraries

I'm really freaking out!
I've a project with core plo library, I'm trying to build the ipa file but the library isn't included in the final package. 
I've an earlier version of the project (let's say about 2months ago) and it works perfectly. The only thing that has changed in the configuration is the PRODUCT_NAME.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you! 8:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does your lib appear in the Binary libraries list for the running target ?? try removing it and re-adding it.
(Select Project / Target / Build Phases / Link with binary Libraries -- remove it and re-add it)
(Ran into same issue and this fixed my problem. Apparently the precompile headers section in the project settings did not get updated for some reason)

Comment: I've found the problem. Shame on me, in the previous release of the project there was a precompiled copy of the static library added to the app bundle. There is a reason why static library is named "static", that's because the library is statically linked so it is part of the executable. You are absolutely right sometimes re-adding the library helps.